# C# Convert long to bytes gives error: & cannot be applied to long and ulong

Tags: c#, arrays, binary, byte

I want to convert a long to 8 bytes in C# with 100% reliability.

```
public static byte[] ToBytes(this long thisLong)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
        bytes[0] = (byte)(thisLong & 0xFF);
        bytes[1] = (byte)((thisLong & 0xFF00) >> 8);
        bytes[2] = (byte)((thisLong & 0xFF0000) >> 16);
        bytes[3] = (byte)((thisLong & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
        bytes[4] = (byte)((thisLong & 0xFF00000000) >> 32);
        bytes[5] = (byte)((thisLong & 0xFF0000000000) >> 40);
        bytes[6] = (byte)((thisLong & 0xFF000000000000) >> 48);
        bytes[7] = (byte)((thisLong & 0xFF00000000000000) >> 56);
        return bytes;
    }
```

but I get an error on the last line at "thisLong & 0xFF00000000000000":

```
CS0019: Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'ulong' (CS0019)
```

It works OK for int, so any not for long?:

```
public static byte[] ToBytes(this int thisInt)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        bytes[0] = (byte)(thisInt & 0xFF);
        bytes[1] = (byte)((thisInt & 0xFF00) >> 8);
        bytes[2] = (byte)((thisInt & 0xFF0000) >> 16);
        bytes[3] = (byte)((thisInt & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
        return bytes;
    }
```

I don't want to use BitConvertor to avoid issues with endianness.

I don't want to use ulong as converting may fail.

Comment: `bytes[7] = unchecked((byte)(((ulong)thisLong & 0xFF00000000000000) >> 56));`

Comment: `0xFF00000000000000` is a `ulong`. With the MSB set, it can't fit that into `long` as a positive value so the compiler upgrades it to `ulong`. If you right-shift first, then you always do `& 0xFF` and you can avoid the syntax mess that Dmitry suggested.

Comment: Have you looked into BinaryPrimitives? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: You can first *shift*, then *mask*: `bytes[7] = (byte)((thisLong >> 56) & 0xFF);`

Comment: Ah yes, right shift first, good idea, thanks